# How can I create a pentagram?

Tags: modeling

For some reason I want to create a pentagram:

[image]

How can I achieve this in Blender? (I am asking just for the basic shape ⛤⛧⛥✬✫)

Comment: If this were a regular question instead of a peg to hang a tutorial on I would have voted to close it for need of clarification or being opinion-based :D I mean: did you say please in GN or regular curve or mesh object? Or what you need it for afterwards so that we know what to consider while creating it? Or please tell us what you got so far and where you are stuck  ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann for legal reasons I can't explain why I need this.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you were a priest in the Church of Satan, I know others, too :)

Comment: I'd pay a few dollars to learn what draconian legal reasons could possibly exist that someone couldn't describe in generalities why they needed something

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Is this really a pentagram? XD https://snipboard.io/olpdkS.jpg

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I was worried this might be the case, but at least now I have a confirmation, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a 5 vertex circle:

[image]

Fill between the vertices this way:

[image]

Remove the outer edges:

[image]

Enable the *Auto Merge* and the *Split Edges & Faces* options, press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to create vertices where the edges cross:

[image]

Fill everything with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Inset individual faces with double <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

Delete the inset faces, edit the topology a bit, extrude up...

[image]

Comment: Nice, indeed without faces the pentagram won't even be visible.

Answer (score 15):

### Geometry Nodes

You can use a 5-point star with same inner and outer radii, but $108°$/ $180°$ twist:

[image]

In order to improve topology, consider converting it to mesh and merging by distance:

[image]

Comment: "*Hey, I heard you like pentagrams so I drew a pentagram in your node setup, so you can see a pentagram while building a pentagram*"

Comment: You even managed to draw a pentagram with only FOUR points in the node tree, for this you get three upvotes from me! :D

Answer (score 8):

A combination of [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/284728/35559) and [the wizard's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/284724/35559) methods.

Snap is set to 'Vertex' and 'Active', including 'Rotation'. Automerge as in moonboots' answer, starting with a 10-vertex circle:

[image]

Comment: wow this is magic

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this?!

Comment: let's burn mister Robin Betts

Comment: he's a witch, he looks like one!

Comment: You're upsetting the cat! (There, there, Mephistopholes, don't listen to any of the cruel things the villagers are saying.. let's brew them a little something to... um... _calm them down_.. )

Answer (score 5):

small detail which can also work for the crest of the Abbey of Theleme, or for those pictish tattoos.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another variation, without snapping. But my sect does not allow me to say more.

[image]

Comment: You devil... not even the 2 millisecond exposure of the header is any help...

Comment: who said we are here to help?

Comment: Let me guess, R 180? 

Comment: s -1 also works

Comment: @ruckus don't tell this kind of secrets, please... ; )